# Add values to array object in json file

Tags: json, go

I need to add an array of string to a json file.
i.e let's say i have the following json file:

```
{
  "user": {
    "role": "admin",
    "email": "admin@domain.com"
  },
  "region": [
    {
      "location": "EU",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "countries": [
        {
          "FR": [
            {
              "time": "morning",
              "cities": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "NA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "countries": [
        {
          "USA": [
            {
              "time": "evening",
              "cities": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now lets say I have a list of cities that I want to add to region -> countries -> FR

This is my approach, but not sure how to update the cities field.
I have commented the section in the code that need to store to update the list of cities for FA.

```
 func test (jsonFilePath, cityNames string) error {


    jsonBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(jsonFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("template json file is %s\n", jsonBytes)

    var result map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    if _, exists := result["region"]; exists {
        fmt.Printf("Found region\n")
        
        countries := result["region"].([]interface{})
        
        for _, country := range countries {
            
            m := country.(map[string]interface{})
            
            if _, exists := m["FR"]; exists {
                
               /*How to add cityNames to the cities array of the FA?*/
  
            } 

        }
    } else {
        errMsg := "region field is missing"
        return errors.New(errMsg)
    }

    jsonBytes, err = json.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("the new json file is  %s\n", string(jsonBytes))

    // Write back to file
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("newJson.json", jsonBytes, 0644)
    return err
}
```

Note: The json file has other fields which should not be updated, only  Cities filed should be updated; so the preference is to update the Cities field only without defining a struct

Comment: `m["FR"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["cities"].([]interface{}) = append(m["FR"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["cities"].([]interface{}), "France")`

Comment: Why don't you use a struct matching your JSON and umarshal into it? - https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: I recommend defining a struct type which can hold this data instead of navigating through the structure with type assertions.

Comment: Thanks, there are extra fields that should not be changed, so i thought it would be wiser to update it without using struct. I need to only update list of cities.

Comment: @Ashkanxy you might want to [edit] that last bit of information into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's better (i.e. easier and more efficient) to use structs instead of reflection. There are even [websites](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) that can generate a struct from a JSON sample.

But here's how to do it using maps of interfaces:

```
    var result map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &result)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    regions, ok := result["region"].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("region not found")
    }
    for i := range regions {
        region, ok := regions[i].(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        countries, ok := region["countries"].([]interface{})
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        for j := range countries {
            country, ok := countries[j].(map[string]interface{})
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            fr, ok := country["FR"].([]interface{})
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            for k := range fr {
                time, ok := fr[k].(map[string]interface{})
                if !ok {
                    continue
                }
                cities, ok := time["cities"].([]interface{})
                if !ok {
                    continue
                }
                time["cities"] = append(cities, cityNames)
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that in Go maps do not preserve the order, so the order of fields in the output will be different (and also random between runs).